# XmlSerializer in 7.0

Tags: windows-phone-7, xml-serialization

I am using the following line of code for xml serialization in 7.1:
`XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(XElement));`
However XmlSerializer is not present in 7.0 so what is the replacement of it in 7.0??

Comment: Sorry guys, it seems that i added the **System.Runtime.Serialization** instead of **System.xml.Serialization**  
Silly mistake :P

Answer (score 0):

And you could also use datacontractserializer.